# Is using SQL table prefixes necessary?

Tags: 8, upgrading

During an upgrade, there is a setting for the table prefixes to use for the database table.

[image]

Is it a must to use table prefixes? What does using that setting help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if you were to install another Drupal, 7 or 8 on the same database (zentech0_Benia), using prefix will prevent causing confusion/collision.

Ex:

having two tables named accesslog is confusing.

while having site1_acesslog, site2_acesslog you know which accesslog belongs to which site.

In conclusion, if you don't plan on installing another Drupal 7 or 8 in zentech0_Benia, (having 2 websites in the same database) then you don't need table prefixes.